# How can I restore Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 to Visual studio 2013 update 4 without uninstalling entire product

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, ctp4

I have to use Web Essentials 2013 but it is not available for Visual studio 2013 update 5.I would have to have VS 2013 update 4 installed in order to install Web Essentials 2013. Is there is any way I can install VS 2013 update 4 without uninstalling entire VS 2013 update 5 to save time.

Comment: update installs tones of files how can I remove every one of them.I went to Control Panels but there are several products installed which one should I remove.

Comment: I have also tried Extensions & Updates as well there is also no option for removing it.Is there is anybody who have faced same situation

Answer (score 7):

Open up the control panel in Windows.  Click Programs and click view installed updates and search for "Visual Studio 2013 Update 5"  Right click on it and select uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Updates to Visual Studio are implemented as Windows updates. So, you can find the update by visiting the Programs control panel category, and choosing View installed updates under the Programs and Features subcategory:

[Control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sq8n.png)

VS2013 updates should be listed under the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 update category.